# Android-call for ndk function from diffrent threads

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, andengine

Today i experienced strange phenomena

My application have a ndk functions that one of them `startStopRecording()` start and stop video recording(with FFMPEG)

When i call this function from regular Android UI buttons,or Android MenuOptions, the function work perfectly(in the last 3 month)

But,when i call this function from a sprite that attached to glSurfaceView(created with AndEngine),the  application freeze(the gl surface freeze,but from the menu options still function well and can recording while the glsurface freeze) ,with no error,or FATAL ERROR that i cant reproduced as i don't get it any more.but the function that called is the same one that works always,just called from different Places.

My code:

```
Spritebutton20 = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH-3*(CAMERA_WIDTH/12), 1*CAMERA_HEIGHT/12,        CAMERA_WIDTH/7, CAMERA_HEIGHT/7 ,mCloudTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
          @Override
          public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float     pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()){    
                 startStopRecording();
                        }
                return true;
        }
    };
```

It is really strange as the same function works well for months from Android buttons and Menu,but i switched all my buttons for gl surface(i have to use this for advanced animation GUI in my app).

Is any one know what i missing here?maybe it is a threads conflict issue?
I tried to add timer to check that the function  called only once in a time,  but it still crash the application.

How to debug it?

EDIT:
This scenario is happens in 50% of the time.it mean sometimes it work and sometimes it freeze.
From a point of view of Computer Sciences-how it could happen that sometimes it happens and sometimes not.it is really 50/50,even in the same application run.

EDIT 2:
Solved with Alex cohn comment.run it on UI thread is safe enough and works as expected.

Comment: Error message other than FATAL ERROR?

Comment: i Edit my question.just the glsurface freezing.but anly when i call to this function.hard to debug :\

Comment: It's not very clear from the little piece of published code, what goes wrong 50% of the time. Actually, many things cold go wrong, and it's not my intention to try understand your code in all complexity. But the simple solution that comes to mind, why not call the `startStopRecording()` on UI thread? If you have access to an activity, call **activity**.[runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) `( new Runnable() { public void run() {  startStopRecording(); } } );`

Comment: That's actually what i did and intend to post as solved.by you preceded me so your answer is right.i will edit as solved.and it make sense as Android widget(which works for me) run on UI thread.hope i'm right. many Thnaks!